# Graphite not showing correct values

Tags: graphite, statsd

Basically, my problem is Graphite is not showing the correct data, as if it is not aggregating the data properly.

What I want to do is create a view counter using Graphite.

## My Configuration

I'm using `Node-StatsD` to send data to Carbon:

```
var client = new StatsD({
    host: config.host,
    port: config.port,
    prefix: config.prefix
});
client.increment("bucketName");`
```

I have the following storage-schemas.conf:

```
[default]
pattern = .*
retentions = 1h:14d,1d:99y
```

and everything else is on default including storage-aggregation.conf, which by default uses the aggregation method sum and has xFilesFactor of 0.

## The Problem

I've confirmed that the data is able to reach Graphite as it did create my bucket and `stats.counters.statsd.metrics_received.count` does increase.

However my bucket count does not increase, here are the results of my query:

1. `target=bucket.count&rawData=true` gives
   `bucket.count,1553497200,1553583600,3600|0.0,0.0,0.0,...,0.0,0.0`
2. `target=summarize(bucket.count,"1d")&format=json` gives
   `{"datapoints": [[0.0, 1553472000], [0.0, 1553558400]], "target":...}`
3. `hitcount(bucket.count,"1d")` gives
   `{"datapoints": [[3600.0, 1553497200]], "target":...}`

`hitcount` does give something that is not 0 but the count is way more than I send to Graphite. I sent at most 1 or 2 dozen in the last hour.

Comment: What is your statsd flush interval?

Comment: @Popieluch oh thanks it would seem its the flush interval that is the problem. I still have it on the default 10 seconds which might be causing the data to keep getting overwritten.

Comment: So I changed the flush interval and the problem still persists. :(

Comment: So apparently I manage to solve it by using `deleteIdleStats: true,` in StatsD's config.js